# Multiple draggable markers not updating

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I implemented multiple draggable markers into my google map. Now I have the problem that my coordinates don't seem to update except from the last one.

I don't get any mistake but only marker 10 updates the position and address.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.012904492831055, 4.3322019042968805),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.012904492831055, 4.3322019042968805);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: 'Point ' + (i+1),
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
            updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
            updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
            updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });
}

// Update current position info.
updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
geocodePosition(latLng);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's variable scoping problem, `var marker` is a global variable inside the loop and being updated through the loop, so last value is being set at the end of the loop.

Just wrap your every `google.maps.event.addListener` inside a function, i.e.

```
(function(marker){ // Inside this function 'marker' is a local variable.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    });
})(marker); // Pass the 'global' marker variable as an argument
```

Answer (score 2):

When your events `dragstart`,`drag`,`dragend` are being triggered , `marker` variable is linked to the last `Marker` you have created, as by that time your loop is already ended.

Try the belowed trick to avoid that situation:

```
 //..............
 (function(marker){   //added line
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    });
 })(marker);   //added line
 //..............
```

*Alternatively* you can use `this` for referencing the marker, on which your listener is added:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
      updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
      updateMarkerPosition(this/*instead of 'marker'*/.getPosition());
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
      updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
      geocodePosition(this/*instead of 'marker'*/.getPosition());
 });
```